# This method does not accept null for this parameter. But the texture is programmed as loaded, in my view?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm going to create a game for myself to learn, but I ran into a problem, and I really don't know how to fix it.

The error is:

```
This method does not accept null for this parameter.
```

I've searched and it tells me I have not loaded the texture correctly, which I think I did. Because it's before the Draw command.

Heres my Game1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Eggt_Fast

    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the main type for your game
        /// </summary>
        public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
        {
            GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

            Player player = new Player();

            public Game1()
            {
                graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
                Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
                this.Window.Title = "Eggt Fast";
                graphics.ApplyChanges();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
            /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
            /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any             components
            /// and initialize them as well.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void Initialize()
            {
                // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

                base.Initialize();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
            /// all of your content.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void LoadContent()
            {
                // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
                spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

                // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
            /// all content.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void UnloadContent()
            {
                // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
            /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
            protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                // Allows the game to exit
                if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                    this.Exit();

                // TODO: Add your update logic here

                player.Update(gameTime);
                base.Update(gameTime);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
            protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

                // TODO: Add your drawing code here
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                player.Draw(spriteBatch);
                spriteBatch.End();

                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my Player.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace Eggt_Fast
{
    class Player
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 position;
        public int speed;

        public Rectangle boundingBox;
        public bool isColliding;


        public Player()
        {
            texture = null;
            position = new Vector2(300, 300);
            speed = 14;
            isColliding = false;
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player");
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White); //THE ERROR IS HERE.
        }


        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `LoadContent` *isn't* called before `Draw` as you suspect; or `Content.Load` is returning `null`.

Comment: How would I fix this? How can I call LoadContent before Draw, like it is stated in the code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you never call `Player.LoadContent()`. Since you don't call this from your `Game1.LoadContent()`, the texture is never loaded, which is what is causing the error. To fix your problem you could try something like this:

In Game1

```
protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            player.LoadContent(Content);
        }
```

This will call the `LoadContent` void in your player class, which is what I think you initially had in mind would happen automatically. `LoadContent()` won't be called automatically like Game1's `LoadContent` is, because `Player` is just a regular class and doesn't inherit from other classes, like `Game1` does.

Comment: this fixed it for me! Although I had to change it to a lower case p. I was watching a tutorial, and he didn't do it all, and it still worked for him. Don't know how or why.

Comment: Glad it helped. Sorry about that p, I'll fix that.

Comment: @Stepepper In the tutorial the Player was probably a drawablegamecomponent and was added to the games components in the game-constructor or something like that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent.aspx